# Interpolating missing values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I have a dataset that tracks snapshots of cellphone battery levels and connection.  However, when a cellphone loses connection, it will report the same numbers as its last good connection, for example:

```
   id           timestamp connection bat_level
1   1 2019-09-12 20:00:00       TRUE         4
2   1 2019-09-12 20:05:00       TRUE         4
3   1 2019-09-12 20:10:00       TRUE         4
4   1 2019-09-12 20:15:00       TRUE         4
5   1 2019-09-12 20:20:00       TRUE         3
6   1 2019-09-12 20:25:00      FALSE         3
7   1 2019-09-12 20:30:00      FALSE         3
8   1 2019-09-12 20:35:00      FALSE         3
9   1 2019-09-12 20:40:00      FALSE         3
10  1 2019-09-12 20:45:00      FALSE         3
11  1 2019-09-12 20:50:00      FALSE         3
12  1 2019-09-12 20:55:00      FALSE         3
13  1 2019-09-12 21:00:00       TRUE         1
14  1 2019-09-12 21:05:00       TRUE         1
15  1 2019-09-12 21:10:00      FALSE         1
16  1 2019-09-12 21:15:00      FALSE         1
17  1 2019-09-12 21:20:00      FALSE         1
18  1 2019-09-12 21:25:00      FALSE         1
19  1 2019-09-12 21:30:00      FALSE         1
20  1 2019-09-12 21:35:00      FALSE         1
21  1 2019-09-12 21:40:00      FALSE         1
22  1 2019-09-12 21:45:00      FALSE         1
23  1 2019-09-12 21:50:00      FALSE         1
24  1 2019-09-12 21:55:00      FALSE         1
25  1 2019-09-12 22:00:00      FALSE         1
```

My objective is to create a fifth column that essentially interpolates what is happening when `connection` = FALSE.  I would like to interpolate the battery drain rate at .05 per minute (cannot go lower than 0), starting from the value of the **last TRUE connection**, so the output would be :

```
   id           timestamp connection bat_level theoretical_bat_level
1   1 2019-09-12 20:00:00       TRUE         4                    NA
2   1 2019-09-12 20:05:00       TRUE         4                    NA
3   1 2019-09-12 20:10:00       TRUE         4                    NA
4   1 2019-09-12 20:15:00       TRUE         4                    NA
5   1 2019-09-12 20:20:00       TRUE         3                    NA
6   1 2019-09-12 20:25:00      FALSE         3                  2.75
7   1 2019-09-12 20:30:00      FALSE         3                  2.50
8   1 2019-09-12 20:35:00      FALSE         3                  2.25
9   1 2019-09-12 20:40:00      FALSE         3                  2.00
10  1 2019-09-12 20:45:00      FALSE         3                  1.75
11  1 2019-09-12 20:50:00      FALSE         3                  1.50
12  1 2019-09-12 20:55:00      FALSE         3                  1.25
13  1 2019-09-12 21:00:00       TRUE         1                    NA
14  1 2019-09-12 21:05:00       TRUE         1                    NA
15  1 2019-09-12 21:10:00      FALSE         1                  0.75
16  1 2019-09-12 21:15:00      FALSE         1                  0.50
17  1 2019-09-12 21:20:00      FALSE         1                  0.25
18  1 2019-09-12 21:25:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
19  1 2019-09-12 21:30:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
20  1 2019-09-12 21:35:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
21  1 2019-09-12 21:40:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
22  1 2019-09-12 21:45:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
23  1 2019-09-12 21:50:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
24  1 2019-09-12 21:55:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
25  1 2019-09-12 22:00:00      FALSE         1                  0.00
```

I understand that one should use a cte with `lag()`, but not sure how to get start decreasing the `theoretical_bat_level` from the last `TRUE` value per `id`

```
CASE WHEN connection = FALSE AND 
LAG(connection) OVER(PARTITION BY id, timestamp ASC) = True AND
connection = LAG(bat_level) OVER(PARTITION BY id, timestamp ASC) THEN  ?
WHERE connection = FALSE
```

Any guidance on the right method to use here would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution needs a helper function that calculates the length of an interval in minutes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION int_minutes(interval) RETURNS double precision
   LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT EXTRACT (minutes FROM $1)
       + 60 * extract (hours FROM $1)
       + 1440 * extract (days FROM $1)';
```

Then you could use a window function to get the latest time when the phone was connected:

```
SELECT id, timestamp, connection, bat_level,
       greatest(bat_level
                - int_minutes(timestamp
                              - conn_ts_arr[cardinality(conn_ts_arr)]
                  ) * 0.05,
                0.0
       ) AS theoretical_bat_level
FROM (SELECT id, timestamp, connection, bat_level,
             array_agg(timestamp)
                FILTER (WHERE connection)
                OVER (PARTITION BY id
                      ORDER BY timestamp) AS conn_ts_arr
      FROM cellbat) AS s1
ORDER BY id, timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close you need to coalesce the value you generated with last time with the bat_level so you only use bat level the first time

Like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN connection = FALSE AND 
       LAG(connection) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ASC) = True 
  THEN COALESCE(LAG(THEORETICAL_BAT_LEVEL) OVER(PARTITION BY id, timestamp ASC),
       LAG(bat_level) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ASC)) - .25 
  ELSE NULL AS THEORETICAL_BAT_LEVEL
```

Comment: thanks, also there should be a condition that prevents subtraction if already at 0, and `theoretical_bat_level` doesn't exist as a column in the table so how could it be referenced in a `CASE WHEN` statement ?

Comment: @the_darkside -- good point about already at 0 -- lag will return null on the first row in the partition

Comment: is it possible to `COALESCE()` a column that doesn't exist yet though ?

Comment: @Hogan . . . You can use the three-argument form of `lag()` to pass in a default value.

Comment: not sure I get it, so I should replace `THEORETICAL_BAT_LEVEL` with `bat_level`  in the COALESCE statement?

Comment: also shouldn't it be `PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ASC` ?

Comment: @the_darkside -- no the coalesce statement should be correct, but I did not test -- are you getting an error?  and yes you are right about the order by

Comment: I am using PrestoSQL, yes I think because here:

`COALESCE(LAG(THEORETICAL_BAT_LEVEL) OVER(PARTITION BY id, timestamp ASC),
       LAG(bat_level) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ASC)) - .25 `

you can't COALESCE a column that doesn't exist

Comment: yes, that's the error - that it can't resolve that column

Comment: ok then you need to do a sub query that gets a partial result and then use lag on that sub query columns (ugly but will work)

Comment: also, coalesce creates an array and you can't subtract a float from an array

Comment: ah yes that's true, but this solution is not working for some reason